# How to access canvas width outside of the onDraw method Android

Tags: java, android, canvas, initialization, width

I have the following code:

```
Bitmap right1;

public TicTacToe(Context context) {
    super(context);
    right1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.plus);
    int width = right1.getWidth();
    int height = right1.getHeight();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    right1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(right1, canvas.getWidth()/3, canvas.getWidth()/3, false);
    canvas.drawBitmap(right1, (canvas.getWidth() - (canvas.getWidth()/3)), 0, null);
    invalidate();
}
```

I want to rescale the bitmap that is called "right1" based off of what the width of the canvas is. I succeeded in doing this, but the line of code that does this is the third line under the onDraw method. The problem with that line of code is that it will constantly loop when I would like to only run it once. Idealy I would like to put that line of code within the TicTacToe method, but I am unsure how to initialize the canvas within the TicTacToe method so that I can get the canvas width.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this stuff inside constructor just add condition in onDraw() method.

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        if(right1==null){
            right1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(right1, canvas.getWidth() / 3, canvas.getWidth() / 3, false);
            canvas.drawBitmap(right1, (canvas.getWidth() - (canvas.getWidth() / 3)), 0, null);
            invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That would make it better, but the code would constantly check this if statement all the time. So it would still be better to initialize it once in the constructor and never have to check for it in the onDraw method

Comment: That because the onDraw() was in infinite call so once you draw do not call invalidate() method so I update the code and put the invalide() call in if() block now it will call only once